# How to do prototypal inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I've tried several ways but I couldn't do it.

On the next example I want the Soldier gets all properties of Person, and allowing to add more properties. How to do it correctly?

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.hi = function (message) {
    console.log(message + "!!!");
};

var Soldier = new(Person); // it is not the way to do it

Soldier.prototype.good_hi = function (message) {
    console.log("Sir! " + message + ", sir!");
};
```

Comment: Does googling for "javascript inheritance" come up with nothing?

Comment: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `Soldier` constructor. You need to make that first. Then you'd apply the `Person` constructor to new `Soldier` instances.

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.hi = function (message) {
    console.log(message + "!!!");
};

function Soldier(name, age) {
    Person.apply(this, arguments);
}

Soldier.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // is better
Soldier.prototype.constructor = Soldier;

Soldier.prototype.good_hi = function (message) {
    console.log("Sir! " + message + ", sir!");
};
```

---

Then use it like this:

```
var s = new Soldier("Bob", 23);

s.good_hi("Hello");
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/3kGGA/

Comment: You forgot `Soldier.prototype.constructor = Soldier;` Otherwise, the constructor will be `Person` from the prototype object you assign.

Comment: @millimoose: added it in to be complete.