# How to tell WebStorm to resolve inherited methods?

Tags: javascript, prototype, webstorm

I'm doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334476/how-to-do-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript).
My issue is that WebStorm (11) marks inherited method calls `unresolved`. How could I fix it?

Based on the example in the link, it marks `hi` unresolved:

```
Soldier.prototype.good_hi = function (message) {
  console.log('Sir!');
  this.hi(message);
  console.log('Sir!');
};
```

Comment: So `Soldier` inherits from the prototype of `Person`, which has the `hi` function? I'm afraid there's only so much checking that your IDE can do. And complex prototype hierarchies make this harder, especially using vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @type{Person}
 */
var Soldier = function (name, age) {
  Person.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Notice that apart from the annotation added I changed the way the function was created.